How to run NiFi throughout nginx with secure connection
I have NiFi with OpenId authentication via Keycloak. Everything works great. But an additional task appeared: accessing NiFi via Nginx. I configured everything according to the NiFi documentation, but I keep getting an error :(

config nginx:

    location /nifi {
        proxy_set_header X-ProxyScheme "https";
        proxy_set_header X-ProxyHost "proxy-host";
        proxy_set_header X-ProxyPort "443";
        proxy_set_header X-ProxyContextPath "/nifi";
        proxy_pass https://nifi-host.com:8443;
    }


nifi.properties

nifi.web.proxy.context.path=/
nifi.web.proxy.host=proxy-host:443

At the first request, https://proxy-host:443/nifi works honestly and goes to https://nifi-host.com:8443/nifi/. The following redirect should lead to the page https://nifi-host.com:8443/nifi-api/oauth2/authorization/consumer to receive a token, but redirects to https://proxy-host:443/nifi/nifi-api/oauth2/authorization and the browser complains that it says 404 not found - this is understandable, because There is no keycloak on the nginx host. how to force nginx to further substitute not the URL of the proxy host, but the URL of the target host with NiFi in order to receive a token and further communicate with NiFi libraries?
Thanks in advance for any ideas!

I have solved the problem. the problem was in the "~" symbol in another location of the same nginx, that is, at first the redirect was correct, but then during the authentication process nifi went to another location and as a result there was an error "404 not found"

I found the problem is certifiate between proxy and nifi. I export certificate from jks and add to proxy certificate on nginx. Here is setup on NGINX:
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        http2 on;
        server_name  nifi.proxy.vn;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/certs/tls.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/tls.key;
        ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/nifi-cert.pem;
        #ssl_verify_client off;
        proxy_ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/nifi-tls.crt;
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/nifi-tls.key;
        proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/nifi-cert.pem;
        location / {
            proxy_pass       https://xxxxx:9443;
            proxy_set_header X-ProxyScheme https;
            proxy_set_header X-ProxyHost nifi.proxy.vn;
            proxy_set_header X-ProxyPort 443;
            proxy_set_header X-ProxiedEntitiesChain "$ssl_client_s_dn";
        }
    }

